# Convert byte* to HEX String

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a `uint8_t` buffer into a HEX String:

```
uint16_t len = b.length();
char* result = (char*) malloc(len * 2 * sizeof(char));
int resPos=0;
while (len > 0) {
    uint8_t *buffer;
    uint8_t bytesToRead = min(32, len); 
    buffer = b.readBuffer(bytesToRead);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytesToRead; i++) {
        char buf[3];
        sprintf(buf, "%02X", buffer[i]);
        OutPut.println(buf);
        //memcpy(result + resPos , buf,2);
        //resPos+=2;
        //OutPut.println(resPos);
    }

    len -= bytesToRead;
}
```

Without the commented lines, I can see in my output, the hex values one at a time.

What I would like to do, on the commented code, is return the whole HEX value as a `char*`. I tried the commented code and I have some memory errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commented code is almost correct.

You forgot just one thing: C strings are zero terminated, and you forgot to terminate your string.

Comment: where ? `result[resPos+2]=0` before the println ?

Comment: ehm.. 1) yes. after the increment you don't even need the `+2`. 2) preferably ,if you don't want to print within the loop, then only after the loop. 3) you could directly sprintf in the `result`.

Comment: yes printing was only for debugging purposes. It will be removed altogether. I think the problem is something else, because as soon as I memcopy it keeps rebooting (I'm programming a microcontroller).

Comment: it's just C, you should be able to compile and *test* most of it on other architectures...

Comment: Yep, but this particular micro-controller has an issue when it runs out of memory, which was caused by the malloc (`len` is quite big). So I was having unexpected behaviour. Now I send my data 32 bytes at a time and it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
char buf[3];

result[0] = '0'; result[1] = 'x'; result[2] = 0;
or
memcpy(result, "0x");

for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    itoa(buffer[i], buf, 16);

    strcat(result, buf);
}
```

valter

Comment: why the '0' and 'x' ?

Comment: @MajidL So the result is `"0xa64"` instead of `"a64"`