# How to represent address of a variable as a String?

Tags: c, printf

I have to reproduce the printf function in C.
I am getting problem with printing addresses (%p).
So i have an address of variable and I need to return it as an array of char.
Is it even possible?

```
char *ptrToString(void * x)
{   
    char *t = (char *)x;
    printf("Here: %s\n",t);
    return "abc";
}

char *getPtr(unsigned long long x)
{
    return ptrToString(&x);
}
```

Comment: So `printf("%p", (void*) thePointer)` – cast necessary to avoid undefined behaviour as `%p` explicitly requires a `void*` pointer (though on nowadays machines there wouldn't be any difference...).

Comment: Not directly related to your question: in `getPtr` `&x` is the address of the parameter `x` which is a local variable which is probably not what you want. [Edit] and show an example of how you would call `getPtr` and what exactly it is supposed to return.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341818/convert-byte-to-hex-string

Comment: To produce a string representation of a pointer, convert the pointer to an unsigned integer type wide enough to represent it fully, then format the unsigned integer as you desire, e.g., into a hexadecimal format as you would for any unsigned integer value. (If your C implementation uses a flat address space, no further work is necessary. if your C implementation has some other address structure, you could format the unsigned integer to display that, e.g., separating the segment and offset parts.)

Comment: Another alternative is to read the bytes that represent the pointer as `unsigned char` values (convert the address of the pointer to `unsigned char *`) and format those bytes as desired.

Comment: @AllanWind: No, that question is about converting a binary numeral in a string to hexadecimal. It is not about formatting addresses.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, update it to a different one.  It's definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a small note:

```
char *getPtr(unsigned long long x)
{
    return ptrToString(&x);
}

int main() 
{
   long long someLong = 1;
   char *ptr = getPtr(someLong);
   return 0;
}
```

Here ptrToString will return the address of variable x on the stack rather than the address of variable someLong because the value of the variable will get copied on the stack as a totally separate entity.

As for the answer itself, an address is actually just a number representing byte offsets in memory. To convert this number to a string, you need a variant integer to ascii-like function where you convert to base 16 instead of base 10.

I assume `sprintf` is not an option, so you'll have to implement your own variant of a decimal to hex string converter. Cast any address to a wide unsigned integer type and convert that number to hex.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are numeric types, so in `printf`-like functions use either `%p` (preferred), `%x` or `%d` to print them.

Your ptrToString could look something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *x = "test";

char *ptrToString(void *x) {
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(void*) * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(s, "%p", x);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char *a = ptrToString( (void*) x);

    if (!a)
        return 1;

    printf("%s\n", a);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That buffer `s` will be undersized, depending on how addresses are represented when extruded via `%p`. Running through [an address sanitizer](https://godbolt.org/z/f8q8heY38) will tell you as much. Unrelated, the argument ot `ptrToString` should be `const void*`, thereby eliminating the need for the superfluous, and potentially dangerous cast to `void*` in `main` at the call site.

Comment: oh, yes you are right, '%p' adds some additional characters, I guess '%d' would be OK.

Comment: To prevent what @WhozCraig is talking about, you can call `snprintf` with a `size=0` argument and then allocate a buffer of the size that the function returns.

Comment: @WhozCraig it is undersized for 3 reasons: 1. there is no space for the null terminator. 2. there is a factor 2 missing, because for each byte we need two chars. 3. `%p` may produce a prefix like `0x`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Exactly. `%p ` could produce near-anything the implementation sees fit in representing a pointer as a string. The size/width of the physical pointer is marginally relevant.  [A solution using `snprintf`](https://godbolt.org/z/a4eE1876a) is a far better option.

Comment: @WhozCraig sure `snprintf` is the best solution, but as he needs to replicate `printf`, I'm not sure if he's allowed to use  `snprintf`...